# Factory pattern using interface. Get "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I followed [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-factory-pattern-example) tutorial, trying to make my own Factory pattern class. This is what I got (minimized):

```
interface Database{
    public void connect();
}

class MySQL implements Database{
    private String host;
    private String db_name;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    MySQL(String _host, String _db_name, String user, String password){
        // ... initialization
    }
    public void connect(){
        // ... not so important
    }
}

class DatabaseFactory{
    public static Database init(int idx, String _host, String _db_name, String _user, String _password){
        Database db = null;
        switch(idx){
            case 1:
                db = new MySQL(_host, _db_name, _user, _password);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return db;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Database db = new DatabaseFactory.init(1, "localhost", "db", "root", "root");
    }
}
```

When I compile this code, I get this error message from the compiler:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> Db.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
>           Database d = new DatabaseFactory.init(1, "localhost", 3306, "db",
>
> symbol:   class init ^
>
> location: class DatabaseFactory
>
> 1 error

I do not know, what I'm doing wrong and how I can solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the new in front of DatabaseFactory

Comment: Pheeew. That's it. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared "init" method as static in DatabaseFactory class.

Get rid of the new operator.

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.init(1, "localhost", "db", "root", "root");
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Db.java:66: error: cannot find symbol Database d = new DatabaseFactory.init(1, "localhost", 3306, "db");
```

Expects the to be an static inner class called 'init' in `DatabaseFactory` as follows:

```
public class DatabaseFactory {

  public static class init {
     public init(int i, String name, int port, String user, String pwd) {
       ...
     }
  }
}
```

But this is not what you want at all. Since init() is a static method, simple call it using:

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.init(param);
```

Above I have not specified your parameters. I notice in your code, the init method has a signature of `(int,String,String,String,String)` but according to the error message, you call it with `(int, String, int,?...)`. Make sure you call it with the same parameter types.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!